# What is year 0 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

Take the following code

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setFullYear(0);
alert(d);
```

What year is year 0000? After all, year 0 isn't actually a thing, since we went from 1BC to 1AD. Is year 0 actually 1BC and year -1 actually 2BC?

Comment: January, 1st 1970

Comment: I think the issue is that "BC" and "AD" do not lie on the same number line as you have pointed out, they are offset by one. Thus, I would assume that all years in Javascript are "AD" (even the negative ones). So yes, I believe you are correct.

Comment: @zer00ne no, that's `new Date(0)`

Comment: Why is this useful to know? No date from that time back then is accurate, so if these dates are +-30 years, why does 1 year matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ES262 specification says:

> **20.3.1.3 Year Number**
>
> ECMAScript uses a proleptic Gregorian calendar to map a day number to a year number and to determine the month
> and date within that year.

If you look up [proleptic Gregorian calendar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar) on Wikipedia, you'll find:

> For these calendars one can distinguish two systems of numbering years BC. Bede and later historians did not use the Latin zero, nulla, as a year (see Year zero), so the year preceding AD 1 is 1 BC. In this system the year 1 BC is a leap year (likewise in the proleptic Julian calendar). Mathematically, it is more convenient to include a year 0 and represent earlier years as negative, for the specific purpose of facilitating the calculation of the number of years between a negative (BC) year and a positive (AD) year.

Therefore it is up to your interpretation wether year 0 exists or not.